# How to use component with global register in Vue Cli3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli-3

This is my folder

```
+src
  +components
    +Logo.vue
App.vue
main.js
```

In my main.js I had been import the file

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import Logo from '@/components/Logo.vue'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

This is my App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Logo />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

  }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

And I was stucked at how to link my Logo.vue into App.vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register the component globally by using:

```js
app.component("Logo", Logo);
```

#### Example:

```js
...

const app = createApp(App);

// Register component globally
app.component("Logo", Logo);

app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");

...
```

Read more in the official [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#global-registration).